Swww code 1 error
Yesterday, I upgraded Wayland to version 1.23 to install Gamescope, but it didn’t work for me. After rebooting, swww didn’t start. When I tried to launch swww, it said to run swww-daemon. However, when I tried running swww-daemon, I got the following output
sekullarx@Nitro5  ~  swww-daemon                            

thread 'main' panicked at daemon/src/wayland/interfaces.rs:53:13:
Protocol error on interface wl_display. Code 1: invalid arguments for wl_registry#2.bind
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
 ✘ sekullarx@Nitro5  ~  RUST_BACKTRACE=1 swww-daemon

thread 'main' panicked at daemon/src/wayland/globals.rs:163:81:
called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Os { code: 32, kind: BrokenPipe, message: "Broken pipe" }
stack backtrace:
note: Some details are omitted, run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=full` for a verbose backtrace.
 ✘ sekullarx@Nitro5  ~  RUST_BACKTRACE=full swww-daemon

thread 'main' panicked at daemon/src/wayland/interfaces.rs:53:13:
Protocol error on interface wl_display. Code 1: invalid arguments for wl_registry#2.bind
stack backtrace:
   0:     0x62c9d7771f0c - <unknown>
   1:     0x62c9d772b133 - <unknown>
   2:     0x62c9d7742b72 - <unknown>
   3:     0x62c9d7776c62 - <unknown>
   4:     0x62c9d7776acb - <unknown>
   5:     0x62c9d777722c - <unknown>
   6:     0x62c9d7776d38 - <unknown>
   7:     0x62c9d7776c99 - <unknown>
   8:     0x62c9d7776c8c - <unknown>
   9:     0x62c9d770276f - <unknown>
  10:     0x62c9d7712e47 - <unknown>
  11:     0x62c9d771882c - <unknown>
  12:     0x62c9d7707bb3 - <unknown>
  13:     0x62c9d772325a - <unknown>
  14:     0x78c29862a1ca - __libc_start_call_main
                               at ./csu/../sysdeps/nptl/libc_start_call_main.h:58:16
  15:     0x78c29862a28b - __libc_start_main_impl
                               at ./csu/../csu/libc-start.c:360:3
  16:     0x62c9d7704b35 - <unknown>
  17:                0x0 - <unknown> 

I downgraded to version 1.22, but it didn’t work. I then upgraded back to 1.23, which also didn’t solve the issue. Currently, I’m using version 1.23.90, but the problem persists. I have reinstalled swww 2-3 times, but nothing has changed.
I’m using Ubuntu Hyprland 24.04 LTS.
Any help?
